# How to share data between components in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to share data from one component to another component like body component to header component using service but not working. After I click the change header details button I want to change the header data details like id and name.

body.component.ts:

```
  change(){ 
  this.details = {
    id:"45673",
    name:"Micheal"
  } 
  this.data.changeMessage(this.details);  
  }
```

common.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {

 details={
   id:'12345',
   name:'Victor'
 }

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.details);
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: any) {
    this.messageSource.next(message);
  }

}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ep7tes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbody%2Fbody.component.ts

Comment: You're describing communication between two components using a service, but only showing one of the components. Also *"not working"* isn't very informative. Give a [mre], *in the question*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I have two component header and body. Initialy header data is coming from service the I am trying to change from body component.

Comment: I understand that, so *where's the service and the other component*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Can you check my stackblitz ?

Comment: No, the example must be *in the question*, as text. Links to off site resources like Stackblitz can be provided as supplemental.

Comment: 2/3, *so close*.

Comment: @Makizh please include relevant code from `header.component.ts` in the question. `details` isn't defined in `app.component.ts` so this is causing an error `_co.names is undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {
      this.message = message
      console.log(this.message)
    })
  }
```

HTML:

```
<p>
body component:
</p>

<div *ngIf="message">


 {{message.id}}
 {{message.name}}
 </div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhqbti?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcommon.service.ts

Comment: Thanks..Can we do without service? is it possible?

Comment: Sure, check this :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttqra6?file=src/app/common.service.ts

Comment: This link is  not working with service : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhqbti?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcommon.service.ts

Comment: Can u revert back with service?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-72d7us?file=src/app/body/body.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

you change two lines of code and try again

```
 {{names.id}} <====={{details.id}}

   {{names.name}}<====={{details.name}}
```

I think it's work for you

Answer (score -1):

You can use Behavior subject for sharing data between components if your data keep on changing frequently and you need latest data every time.

Otherwise, You can simply use service to share data between components.

1. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-services-for-sharing-data-between-component-using-angular-and-above/
2. https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0

Comment: Can you check my stackblitz.I have used behaviorsubject.